# Method in Java that returns the first odd found in a range

Tags: java

I need to create a method that receives an `int n` and tests all integers between `n*n+1` and `(n+1)*(n+1)-1` and returns the first odd number it encounters. If no such number is found between these bounds the function will return `0`.

I'm trying to figure out how to do it for a while and I don't get it. I'm quite new to Java.

Can someone help me?

I thought in something like that but Eclipse says me that `This method must return a result of type int` and didn't understand why.

```
public static int test(int n){      // receives argument n

        int a = n*n+1;             // calculate lower bound
        int b = (n+1)*(n+1)-1;     // calculate upper bound


        do {

        for (int i = 1; i <=a; i++){
            if (a % i == 0){
                return a;
            } else if (a % i != 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }

        ++a;

    } while (a <= b);

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're dealing with a range of all integers between the lower and upper bounds, or can there be integers missing? If the range includes all integers, something like Zymus's answer below should work, because either the first or second integer in the range must be odd.

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a number is odd, use modulo:

```
n % 2 == 0
```

if the above condition is evaluates to `true`, the number is even. This will evaluate to true if the number is odd:

```
n % 2 != 0
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in that way:

```
public static int firstOdd(int n) {
    int a = n*n+1;             // calculate lower bound
    int b = (n+1)*(n+1)-1;     // calculate upper bound

    // if the lower bound isn't "between the two bounds" so start with the next number
    a++;

    // increase a until the upper bound is reached
    while(a < b) {
        // a is odd
        if(a % 2 == 1) {
            // first odd found
            return a;
        } 
        // try next number ( a = a + 1 )
        a++;
    }

    // no first odd found
    return 0;
}
```

With the `%` operator you can test whether a number is odd:

```
if(number % 2 == 1) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int test(int n){

        int a = n*n+1;             // calculate lower bound
        int b = (n+1)*(n+1)-1;     // calculate upper bound
        int result = 0;

        while (a < b){
            if (a % 2 == 1){
                result = a;
                break;
            }
            a++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
public int firstOdd(int n)  {
    int firstPossible = n * n + 1;
    return
        ((firstPossible % 2) == 1) ? firstPossible : firstPossible + 1;
}
```

This removes the need to loop from the equation. The lower bound is either odd, or even. If it is even, the next number is guaranteed to be odd.

Eclipse is giving you that error because not all code paths return (ie. b > on the first iteration).

Answer (score 0):

I think you over-complicated the code a little bit!

Because you are checking for a number between the bounds, the for loop isn't needed. Simply use a while loop to start at 'a' and iterate through to 'b', returning an odd number if one occurs. If one doesn't, then at the end of the function, it returns zero. Hope the code below helps!

public static int test(int n) {

```
    int a = n*n+1;             // calculate lower bound
    int b = (n+1)*(n+1)-1;     // calculate upper bound

    while(a <= b){
        if(a % 2 != 0){     //checks if the number is odd, and if so
            return a;      // returns the value
        }

        ++a;               //iterates through range of B to A
    }

    return 0;              // Returns zero if no value is found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use two loops, just use one. Use number % 2 != to decide if a number is odd or not.

```
public static int test(int n) {      // receives argument n
    int a = n * n + 1;             // calculate lower bound
    int b = (n + 1) * (n + 1) - 1;     // calculate upper bound

    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Or simply: (since the range is continuous)

```
public static int test(int n) {      // receives argument n
    int a = n * n + 1;             // calculate lower bound
    int b = (n + 1) * (n + 1) - 1;     // calculate upper bound
    // if a is not odd then a + 1 must be odd
    return a % 2 != 0 ? a : a + 1;
}
```